# Oil leak at rear drive shaft... 86 jeep comanche

Tags: jeep, drivetrain

There is a new leak at the rear driveshaft. What could this be and how do i fix? Mechanics cost too much and are unreliable (past experience) the repair manual said if it leaks in the rear the problem is at the front but fr using it so much I lost those pages. HELP?

Comment: You're asking about where the drive shaft attaches to the transmission? Or where the transmission and engine come together?

Comment: Where the driveshaft connects to the rear differential. Thnx. ;)

Comment: It sounds like you need to replace the pinion seal. It's a pretty straight forward job and it sounds like you already have a service manual.

Comment: @Ben - When replacing the pinion seal, isn't there consideration given to the preload on the pinion gear? If not done correctly, you can cause bigger issues with the differential itself, at least on most differentials I've dealt with.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 indeed you want to use an inch pound torque wrench to determine how much torque is required to turn the pinion. You add 5 in lbs when retorquing.